# Double textarea? Symfony 2 with FOSU

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, textarea, fosuserbundle

i have this weird problem, and i really dont know why this happens.
The text areas are doubled and their position is bad.
Look at the image.

[image]

So, the builder looks like:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('imie', 'text', array('label' => false, 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('nazwisko', 'text', array('label' => false, 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('username', null, array('label' => false, 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => false, 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('telefon', 'number', array('label' => false, 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'))
        ->add('plainPassword', 'repeated', array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'options' => array('translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'),
            'first_options' => array('label' => false),
            'second_options' => array('label' => false),
            'invalid_message' => 'fos_user.password.mismatch',
        ))
        ->add('captcha', 'captcha', array(
            'label' => ' ',
            'width' => 200,
            'height' => 50,
            'length' => 6,
            'invalid_message' => 'The captcha code is invalid.'
        ))
    ;
}
```

and the html.twig

http://pastebin.com/2pbHqNyH

Note that im using symfony with twig for 2 weeks and im begginer. And im also new to the FOSU. I just want to change the default look of register form from FOSU to suitable for my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because your `repeated` password contains 2 fields, so the `plainPassword` field rendering contains invalid css structure.

Replace:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.plainPassword, 'Hasło:', {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword, {'attr': {'class':'form-control' }}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

By:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.first, 'Hasło:', {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first, {'attr': {'class':'form-control' }}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.second, 'Hasło:', {'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-3 control-label'}}) }}
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second, {'attr': {'class':'form-control' }}) }}
        {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.second) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

More details: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/repeated.html

Comment: Oh, thats what i was looking for! Thanks! Its working like a charm now :)